# Statistical Mechanics Textbook

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

Although I'll be taking a course on statistical mechanics next term, I'm looking to work through the details of statistical mechanics on my own in the summer. Which textbook would one recommended. I have heard that Schroder's and Kerson Huang's books are good.

Any suggestions? And how do the aforementioned books compare?

Comment: See [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30550/recommendations-for-statistical-mechanics-book). You probably want to be more specific about your level, Schroeder and Huang are _very_ different in difficulty. For a first introduction, you can't go wrong with Schroeder.

Comment: I still haven't done theormodynamics so I'd like a text that does that as well. In addition, I have had only a brief taste of statistical mechanics; the instructor presented it as a prelude/review to a course on condensed matter physics (yes, my college had the order other way around; they've changed it now though). I was deeply unsatisfied witht he review because I never got comfortable with the concepts, where is one thing coming from etc etc. So I'd like a text that has thermo, explains the concepts well and I'd also like/welcome a text that's mathematical.

Comment: Try [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36288/crash-course-in-classical-thermodynamics)?

Comment: Ask your course tutor or lecturer.  The course will have a reading list which will give recommended texts.

Comment: My college uses Schroder's book, but I wanted to see what's the consensus over here. My particular requirements/tastes for a book can be found above in a comment.

Comment: Hi, @Junaid; as I said; although not off-topic to ask for recommendations, better ask such queries at the chat room and also check our big-list for book recommendations ( click  [tag:resource-recommendations] to check all such queries) before asking such question. As that of present query, I would prefer _Reif_'s _Thermodynamics and Statistical Physics_ as a start-up for undergrads; this is much more rigorous and intuitive than Scroeder's, IMO.