Good resource for thermodynamics
I am looking for a good resource (preferably a book) on thermodynamics. I am currently an high schooler -- that pretty much sums up my mathematical qualifications so I was looking for something not too intensive as far as maths prerequisites go = a theory-based book?
My school textbook just skims over formulae which leaves gaping hopes between concepts.
Specifically, I am looking for something which gives in depth knowledge about entropy.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36288/2451 and links therein.
