# Thermodynamics Books Recommendations

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations

What's the best books to understand the basic laws of thermodynamics and other things such as enthalpy, Carnot's cycle, entropy, Maxwell equations etc?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36288/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312422/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5614/25301

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Schroeder: [https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Thermal-Physics-Daniel-Schroeder/dp/0201380277](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201380277). This book is a nice introduction and provides excellent physical intuition, but it does not skimp on the mathematics as well. It is also fairly self-contained and does not assume more than multivariable calculus and elementary mechanics.

Comment: Somehow I wouldn't have imagined that the same Schroeder that did the famous introduction to QFT with Peskin had also written on thermodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

In my judgment, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al is an excellent book, especially in its coverage of the difficult-to-learn subject of the 2nd law of thermodynamics and entropy.  Another good book is Introduction to Engineering Thermodynamics by Smith and Van Ness.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [*Cengal and Boles*](https://cruncheez.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/thermodynamics-an-engineering-approach-5th-edition.pdf).  It is how I learned the basic principles of thermodynamics, and it is a pretty good text for going into the first and second laws, the different ideal cycles (Carnot, Brayton, Otto, Rankine, etc.), as well as refrigeration.  Good luck with your studies!